# The request to obtain paykey PAYPAL

Tags: php, paypal

I have my API credentials:

- Api username
- Api password
- and the app fingerprint
  I need to get the PayPal PayKey.
  this is my form:

  `<div class="container secretPaypal">
          <div class="row">
              <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame"
                    class="standard">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="buy">Buy Now:</label>
                      <input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal"
                             src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
                  </div> <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
          <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="insert_pay_key">
      </form> </div> </div>`

in paypal Documentation :

**Step 3: Insert a Pay Key into the HTML Form**

For the **payKey** input value, replace `insert_pay_key` with a **payKey value** that you recently obtained using a Pay call, and save the HTML file.

Documentation is confusing me and I don't know the request URL or the request params in order to obtain the needed `paykey`.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run your API to request the paykey from the Pay operation, this s part of your initial call. In the document, see steps 1-5 under "Make your first call" - [Adaptive Payments - Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/#make-your-first-call)